# What would make converting Tableau reports to Power BI difficult?

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

I'm working on a project where the client wants to move from Tableau to Power BI. This is going to involve converting a number of Tableau reports to PBI. The client would like to know what features / functionality might exist in a Tableau report or visualization that would make it difficult to convert to PBI?

Note, this is not a question about which product is better. The decision to move to PBI has already been made. The client just wants to know what could make this transition difficult.